# USING STORED PROCEDURE to SUM, GROUP BY and insert to another table with

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have created 3 tables: `item`, `shop` and `stock`. Plus a stored procedure called `inserting`
which inserts to the `shop` table with a given item from the `item` table

```
CREATE TABLE item(
i_id int(11) auto_increment,
i_name varchar(255) not null,
primary key(i_id));
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE shop(
s_id     int(11) auto_increment,
s_name   varchar(255) not null,
s_item   int(11) not null,
s_qty    int(11) not null,
primary  key(s_id),
foreign  key(s_item) references item(i_id)
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE stock(
item     int(11) not null,
total    int(11) not null
);
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting (
IN shop_name varchar(225),
IN shop_item int(11),
IN shop_qty int(11)
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO shop(s_name, s_item, s_qty) 
VALUES
(shop_name, shop_item, shop_qty);

INSERT INTO STOCK(item, total) 
SELECT s_item, SUM(s_qty) FROM shop GROUP BY s_item
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
item = VALUES(item),
total = VALUES(total);
```

The first insert works, but on the second insert when it populates the `stock` table it gives me extra columns, which i'm not expecting.

I have tried using REPLACE INTO and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to get single results, still the results comes as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `stock`;
+------+-------+
| ITEM | TOTAL |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     5 |
|    1 |     9 |
+------+-------+
```

what I am trying to achieve is, group the ITEM column, and sum up the TOTAL to a single row.

what am I doing wrong here, or missing from the query?

thanks.

Comment: By "extra columns" you mean extra rows?

Comment: hehe, yep, sorry for the mix-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `on duplicate key` syntax to work as expected, you need a unique or primary key constraint on the target table, so the database can identify the "duplicate" rows. Same goes for the `REPLACE` syntax.

But your `stock` table does not have a primary key. Consider the following DDL instead:

```
CREATE TABLE stock(
    item     int(11) primary key,
    total    int(11) not null
);
```

Side note: there is no need to reassign column `item` in the `on duplicate key` clause, since it's what is used to identify the conflict in the first place. This is good enough:

```
INSERT INTO STOCK(item, total) 
SELECT s_item, SUM(s_qty) FROM shop GROUP BY s_item
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = VALUES(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this one time, it should work as you expected. But subsequent runs may bring duplicate `ITEM` because of what @gmb said. The table must have a `UNIQUE index` or `PRIMARY KEY`. See more details here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html